# Xamarin Add dividing line into Grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want created this ListView using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMain" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#212121" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid x:Name="GridMain">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row0_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="180" x:Name="Row1_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="180" x:Name="Row2_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row3_Height"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" x:Name="Column0_Width" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Column1_Width" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" x:Name="Column2_Width" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Creator}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Body" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Image Source="VoteUp.png" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgVoteUp_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="VoteDown.png" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgVoteDown_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                            <Image Source="Favorite.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgFavorite_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="Send_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Image Source="Save_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

But now I want to add a line above the first `Label` tag. To create the line I want I use this code:

`<Label HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3" />`

But I don't know where to put it and how, because it is a Grid. I want to add it before the Grid, but that gives me the error:

> The property 'View' is set more than once.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `BoxView` instead of a `Label`.  You could use this layout, placing the `BoxView` in the same Row as the `Label`, but vertically aligned

the other things you could try

1. add another row to the `Grid` for the `BoxView`
2. place the `Grid` inside of a `StackLayout` with the `BoxView`

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use a BoxView. OP will need to wrap listview in something (probably a Grid), before adding the boxview because you can't add multiple items to ContentPage.Content.